# Restrict Alt+Tab to the current monitor in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome3, multi-monitor, alt-tab

How can I tweak <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Gnome 3 so it will iterate windows only in the current **monitor**?

I'm using ArchLinux.

Comment: I would like to know the same thing. I'm using debian (stretch/testing), but I doubt that the distribution has much to do with it.

Comment: Check this one https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1437
Credit to @Vasiliy Bolgar

Comment: KDE plasma has this option in the settings. And a few others (same screen(monitor)/desktop/activity (I don't exactly know what these are for), minimised only, and visible only).

Answer (score 4):

Faced the same issue when bought second monitor. Did this repo with the workaround - https://github.com/reanimatorzon/at4dm

At this time I'm trying to publish this to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3148/alt-tab-for-dual-monitor/, but it is on review yet.

Comment: I right now I've found an older alternative... https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1437/current-screen-only-for-alternate-tab/

Comment: ^ I tried this one (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1437) and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite late, but I actually found an answer for this!

Run this code after Gnome starts:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'imports.ui.altTab.WindowSwitcherPopup.prototype._getWindowList = function() {
let workspace = this._settings.get_boolean("current-workspace-only") ? global.screen.get_active_workspace() : null;
let allWindows = global.display.get_tab_list(Meta.TabList.NORMAL, workspace);
allWindows = allWindows.filter(w => w.get_monitor() === global.screen.get_current_monitor());
return allWindows;
}'
```

All credit goes to **boisdeb** on Reddit, which made [the js code](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/507bqd/only_feature_im_missing_alttab_filterd_by_monitor/) that actually makes this work. It'd be nice if someone actually developed the code into an extension, but for now I can't complain: it works a treat.

Comment: this actually broke my alt tab, so that nothing happens on alt+tab. Nothing that an `alt+f2 r` wouldn't fix though

Comment: What Rombus said :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you are not fixed on using gnome, then:

KDE plasma has this option in the settings. And a few others (same screen(monitor)/desktop/activity (I don't exactly know what these are for), minimised only, and visible only).

Comment: How to fix something in GNOME? Just use KDE :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/310/alt-tab-workspace/), it says "A replacement for Alt-Tab, cycles through apps on current workspace only."

Comment: Yes, it only filters by workspace. Both monitors is on the same workspace in Gnome 3.

Comment: I know, it's not what you are trying to achieve but just for future reference: `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only true` would achieve the same without having to add an extension.

Comment: None of these solutions is working for me :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1437/current-screen-only-for-alternate-tab/) to only switch between applications or windows on your current monitor.
Current monitor here means whichever monitor your mouse cursor is on.